# Jest clear mocks between test cases (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, mocking

I have this simple nodeJS application

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

import {testFunction} from './util'

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(testFunction(), 'result of testFunction')
    res.send('Hello World!')
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})

export { app};
```

This is my jest tests:

```
import request from 'supertest'

describe('test cases', () => {
    const mockTestFunction =  jest.fn()

    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.clearAllMocks() // <---------- it doesn't help to clear
        jest.restoreAllMocks()
        mockTestFunction.mockClear()
        mockTestFunction.mockRestore()
    })

    it('1',   async () => {
        jest.mock('../util', () => ({
            testFunction:  mockTestFunction
        }))

        mockTestFunction.mockReturnValue('test 1')

        const {app} = await import('../expressApp')

        return request(app)
            .get(`/`)
            .expect(200)
            .then((response) => {})
    })

    it('2',  async () => {

        const {app} = await import('../expressApp')

        return request(app)
            .get(`/`)
            .expect(200)
            .then((response) => {}) // here I always get mocked "test 1"
    })
})
```

My purpose is clear mockTestFunction for test "2", but as a result, I get always

"'test 1 result of testFunction'", it mocked it first test case and I can't restore it. I want to restore **mockTestFunction** to original (non-mocked) implementation, it should return "'result of testFunction'"

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what *is* testFunction, and why are you mixing two module systems? Also there is no non-mocked implementation of mockTestFunction, or do you mean the original testFunction? And note that it's easier to test if you separate out the definition of the app object and the part where it starts listening to a port.

Comment: If you *do* mean the original `testFunction`, you probably want https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks - you can require the actual implementation, then use that as the `mockImplementation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `jest.requireActual`,
documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename

Something like:

```
it('2',  async () => {
    jest.mock('../util', () => jest.requireActual('../util'))

    const {app} = await import('../expressApp')

    return request(app)
        .get(`/`)
        .expect(200)
        .then((response) => {})
})
```

Comment: Thanks ) but there is a much better and simpler solution  `jest.unmock('../util')`

Comment: ) Yeah, this is exactly your case, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [mockReset](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreset) is what you're looking for.

> Does everything that mockFn.mockClear() does, and also removes any mocked return values or implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before. You should use [jest.resetAllMocks()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestresetallmocks) instead in `beforeEach`